# Trigger Django Signal from Shell

Tags: django, django-signals

I have configured a signal to run on **post_save** and its working fine in Django admin and  API. But when I try to update the model using mymodel.save() using django shell it does not get triggered.

Is there a workaround as I have to manually update the model and call the save method in some cases.

Comment: 2 years 5 months later, have just discovered the same. Sorry, no answer.